# Reference to pages outside from a wrapper div with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I want to link to another page out of a wrapper div. The reason why I wan't to do this is that in my actual app in the settings page I have a button which reloads all the pages inside the wrapper div.

Here is the code: (this doesn't work)

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="page1">
   <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b" >
     <h1>Page1</h1>
     <a href="#settings">Settings</a>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="main" data-theme="b" >
     <h2>content</h2>
   </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" >
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="settings">
   <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
     <h1>Settings page</h1>
     <a href="#page1">Back</a>
   </div>
   <div id="content" data-role="main" data-theme="b" >
     <h2>content</h2>
   </div>
   <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" >
   </div>
</div>
```

Here the according Jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4Lushdxr/

Comment: Why not just leave all pages under the body and then when reloading pages, remove all pages with id not equal to "settings":  https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4Lushdxr/1/

Comment: its not that easy, I get the new pages via ajax and than insert them into the DOM with the jquery function `.html()` Thats why a wrapper would fit best.

Comment: Just use the append() function instead of html(). It will leave the settings page and simply add all the html you build from the JSON.

Comment: that could work, thanks!